# Do the disc brakes fit?

Tags: disc-brake

I found disk brakes online, [Nashbar](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_537564_-1___204708). I am just wondering if they would fit on my bike. I have a Nishiki Pueblo

Comment: Very vague question, Do you have disc brake mounts on your frame? If you do, i would say yes.. if you don't i would say no...

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see from the latest images available the answer is no. The forks lack a caliper mount. The frame lacks a mount for the rear wheel caliper. Your money would be better spent buying better quality brake pads for the current brakes. The real advantage of discs don't become readily apparent unless you are doing long downhills or riding in wet muddy conditions.  If you have your heart set on disc brakes it makes more financial sense to buy a used bike that is equipped with discs already.